# Usage of ArrayLists for JSwing components

Tags: java, arraylist, checkbox

With my code beeing very long doing basically the same for every component just using a different index I decided to place them all in an ArrayList of the needed type.
My code should en-/disable JSpinners according to CheckBoxes beeing checked.

I made up a code like this:

```
private static void updateGUI(int index){

    boolean enabl = checkBoxes.get(index).isEnabled();
    System.out.println(enabl);
    spinners.get(index).setEnabled(enabl);  
//more irrelevant stuff done here
}
```

So I would just give the index of the used checkbox and it should update the JSpinner accordingly. I placed a line to output the current value of the checkbox, when it triggers the function but it always puts out `true`.

All the checkBoxes are placed in the ArrayList correctly and I cannot find the mistake. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Seems like a workable approach. What's going wrong? What exactly is that you are asking?

Comment: You should probably be using `isSelected` rather than `isEnabled`. Read the documentation.

Comment: I see you use `boolean enabl = checkBoxes.get(index).isEnabled();`, this is always true if this checkbox is enabled, not checked properties

Comment: `private static void updateGUI(int index)` Ummm... are you storing your spinners/checkboxes in static arrays? Really?? So what happens when the window supporting them is destroyed???

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Eyy... Hate on me; I know... I have to admit that I am not that far into this static/non-static thing with java (have been with Pascal before in school) and I am now usually using static classes/functions to export code in other classes for better readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your problem is of a different nature.

If you want to know whether a checkbox is selected, you should be calling 
**[isSelected](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#isSelected%28%29)** instead of *isEnabled*!

Alternatively, you can use an [ItemListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemListener.html) to be notified whenever a checkbox is (un)checked!

Answer (score 1):

`isEnabled()` function does not say if the checkBox is selected. It says if the checkbox is active or not. Try `isSelected()` method.